F0 as a distinguishing factor in certain sibilants?
I am currently planning a research paper about pitch's role in distinguishing [s̪], [s̻], [s̺], [ʂ], and [ɕ], and I don't know if there already exists literature about this. The closest I was able to find was At the Edge of Intonation: The Interplay of Utterance-Final F0 Movements and Voiceless Fricative Sounds which was only performed on German and was based on prosody. I was wondering if anyone here knew of already-existing papers about this.

You mean the onset F0 changes of the following vowels of those voiceless fricatives? To be honest, I can't imagine F0 as a distinguishing factor of voiceless sibilants. Any possible interpretations?

I think I had a misconception writing this; I meant the pitch of the frication itself.

The pitch of the frication itself? But a voiceless fricative itself, has no pitch. Do you mean the pitch of a voiced fricative? The examples you mentioned are all voiceless.
